# How do I extract a subtitle track from an MP4 file in a usable format?

Tags: subtitles, mp4box

I have an MP4 file containing a subtitle track. When I extract it using

```
MP4Box -raw 3:output=track3 myfile.mp4
```

I get a `.tx3g` file - a semi-binary format. My subtitle editors don't support it, and I can't figure out how to convert it to something usable.

I'm using Cinnamon on a fairly recent GNU/Linux distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GPAC/MP4Box maintainer here. Please read this [page on our wiki about subtitling](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/wiki/Subtitling-with-GPAC).

Conversion to srt or vtt can easily be done:

```
gpac -i myfile.mp4 -o subtitles.vtt
```

To get a better support, please go to our [official bug tracker](https://github.com/gpac/gpac/issues). Thanks!

Comment: Oh, well, I didn't consider it an MP4Box bug. Also - I had not realized GPAC and MP4Box are basically the same project.

Comment: Ah ah the issue tracker is not only for issues, but also a place for questions!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ffmpeg` for .vtt or .srt:

```
ffmpeg -i your_file.mkv outfile.vtt
```

[Extract Subtitles](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ExtractSubtitles)

Comment: This works; but - it seems MP4Box and GPAC are more closely "paired", so I'll mark that one as the accepted solution. Thanks and sorry...

Comment: More closely paired?  An `.srt` file is a universal subtitle format.  Not sure what you mean by that.  `ffmpeg/avconv` and `MP4Box/gpac` are the close pair ;-)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant: MP4Box and gpac have the same maintainers, so if my question regards MP4Box, it makes sense to use a gpac solution.

Answer (score 0):

A rather ugly way to do it - but it works:

- Forget about the `.tx3g` file.

#### Phase I:

- If you don't already have it, download/install [MKVToolnix](https://mkvtoolnix.download).
- Start `mkvtoolnix-gui`
- Add your `myfile.mp4` to the sources of a new muxing session
- Keep only the subtitle track (by clearing the other tracks' checkboxes)
- Set a target filename which won't overwrite anything, e.g. `myfile_subs.mks`
- Mux it!

Note: You can achieve the same with `mkvmerge` on the command line, e.g.:

```
mkvmerge \
    --output myfile_subs.mks --no-audio --no-video --no-global-tags \
    --language 2:en '(' my_file.mp4 ')'
```

(for subtitles in English with 0-based track index 2; replace with the values relevant for your file.)

#### Phase II:

- Start a terminal.
- Run `mkvextract myfile_subs.mkv tracks 0:subs.srt`
- You should see something like:

  ```
  Extracting track 0 with the CodecID 'S_TEXT/UTF8' to the file 'subs.srt'. Container format: SRT text subtitles
  Progress:
  ```

  and a progress meter which rises to 100%, at which point you're done.
- Your subtitles are in `subs.srt`.
- Delete `myfile_subs.mks`